# Is it possible to get events for all starred projects from Gitlab API

Tags: gitlab-api

I was wondering if it’s possible to see events with a scope other than “all” or nothing in the events api. For example, I’m interested in seeing “starred projects events”. This is possible in the web version by calling `activity?filter=starred`. Is this possible via API?

Looking at the docs, [Events API | GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/events.html) only see “all” in the example, but nowhere do we see possible values.

Ps: I’m not interested in fetching all the starred projects and then fetching one by one. I would like to do this in just a single request.

Thank you very much.